# Swift extension with inheritance to c# extension methods?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uikit

I'm trying to convert a piece of Swift code to c#.

I know c# method extension but in this case the swift code inherit a class:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return characters.count
  }
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = characters[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do this in c#?

EDIT: The code comes from [here](https://medium.com/@martinlasek/tutorial-adding-a-uitableview-programmatically-433cb17ae07d).

EDIT 2: Found the [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uitableviewsource?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) in the [Xamarin docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/tables/populating-a-table-with-data).

Comment: No, Swift extensions are much more powerful. But this sounds like an XY problem. Why are you trying to convert table view code to C#? Are you possibly using Xamarin.iOS or something?

Comment: `UITableViewDataSource` isn't a class, but a protocol, so this extension declares protocol conformance, not inheritance.

Comment: Indeed I'm using Xamarin.iOS and trying to convert [this sample](https://medium.com/@martinlasek/tutorial-adding-a-uitableview-programmatically-433cb17ae07d).

Comment: @DávidPásztor That would be an interface in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.iOS is based on Objective-C, which will have some difference with swift . In your case , it seems that you want to implement the `DataSource` of **UITableView** , right? If so , you could check the following code

#### 1. Create a subclass of UITableViewSource

```
public class MyTableSource : UITableViewSource {

    string[] characters;
    string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public TableSource (string[] items)
    {
        characters = items;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return characters.Length;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CellIdentifier);
        string item = characters[indexPath.Row];

        //if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null)
        { 
            cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier); 
        }

        cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

#### 2 . In ViewController

```
var TableView = new UITableView(View.Bounds); 
string[] tableItems = new string[] {"111","222","333","444","555","666"};
table.Source = new MyTableSource(tableItems);
```